# Retornar un arreglo con números mayores a 10

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente objetivo: Escribe una función en JavaScript llamada `filter` que reciba un arreglo de números como parámetro y retorne un nuevo arreglo con los números mayores a 10.

```
filter([3, 12, 45, 7]); // retorna [12, 45]
filter([3, 5]);         // retorna []
```

Como puedo hacer para retornar un nuevo arreglo con dichos números mayores a 10?

Mi código lo llevo así:

```
function filter (array){
    var cont = 0;
    for (let i=0; i< array.length; i++){
         if(array[i] >= 10 ){
         cont = cont++;
      }
   }
     return [cont];
}
let resultado = filter([3, 12, 45, 7]);
console.log(resultado);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es exactamente lo mismo que tienes hecho, solo que tienes que cambiar `cont` por un arreglo e ir agregando elementos:

```js
function filter(array) {
  let cont = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > 10) { // Aquí es mayor a 10, no mayor o igual
      cont.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return cont;
}
let resultado = filter([3, 12, 45, 7]);
console.log(resultado);
```

Aunque otra opción es que ocupes el método [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) de Javascript para filtrar los elementos:

```js
const array = [3, 12, 45, 7];

console.log(array.filter(i => i > 10));
```

Answer (score 4):

Tienes bien la primera parte de la lógica que es recorrer el `array` que recibes por parámetro para determinar si cada uno de los elementos es mayor que 10 (ojo que `>=` no debería ser ya que es mayor a 10 o sea > 10), lo que te falta es ir creando el nuevo `array` a medida que encuentras esos valores:

```js
function filter (array){
   var resultArray = [];
   for (let i=0; i< array.length; i++){
         if(array[i] > 10 ){
          resultArray.push(array[i]);
      }
   }
   return resultArray;
}

console.log(filter([1,3,4,20,12,24,2,4,30]));
```

Creamos un `array` vacío (para poder llamar luego al método `push`), si encontramos un elemento con un valor mayor a 10 entonces hacemos `push` del elemento en el `array` (insertamos el elemento).

Answer (score 3):

lo que puedes hacer, es un arreglo interno en la funcion filter, y ese arreglo retornarlo.

```
function filter (array){
    var cont = 0;
    var retorno = new Array();
    for (let i=0; i< array.length; i++){
         if (array[i] >= 10 ){
            retorno[cont]=array[i];
            cont++;
         }
   }
   return retorno;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El prototipo `Array` por defecto incluye el método [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) que sirve exactamente para lo que estás preguntando. Devuelve un nuevo `Array` con los elementos del Array inicial que cumplan una condición dada.

De esta forma lo único que debes hacer es pasar la condición `item > 10` en el filtro.

Usando tu mismo ejemplo, te dejo una prueba.

```js
const array1 = [3, 12, 45, 7];
const array2 = [3, 5];

const filter = array => array.filter(item => item > 10);


const filteredArray1 = filter(array1); // retorna [12, 45]
const filteredArray2 = filter(array2); // retorna []

console.log(filteredArray1);
console.log(filteredArray2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay una forma mucho mas simple para retornar esos numeros mayores a 10:

```js
numeros = [1, 3, 2, 4, 23, 12, 11, 55, 4, 8, 12, 33, 9, 8, 5, 7];
console.log(numeros.filter(n => n > 10));
```

esto te devolveria:

```
[ 23, 12, 11, 55, 12, 33 ]
```

Dentro del filter puedes dar la condicion que necesites. Espero te sirva.